# Are professors paid during sabbatical?

Tags: united-states, salary, sabbatical

Are professors paid during sabbatical? I'm mainly concerned about schools in the US. Answers about other countries are also welcome.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.

Sabbatical is not a vacation but is rather a leave of teaching to focus on research and publication. At many schools it is not automatic but must be applied for and is granted at the provost's discretion.

Some schools will only provide six months of funding, but will release a full year of teaching, making the faculty member responsible for getting grants for the remainder, or effectively working at half salary.

Comment: What are the options for the remainder half? From the host institution?

Comment: External grants. Spouses.

Comment: At my university, one of the requirements when applying for sabbatical is to apply for external funding.  (However, getting the sabbatical is not contingent on getting the funding.)

Comment: @Mark must you be entirely (100%) on external grants or is it 50:50?

Comment: The university pays 50% of the regular annual salary, no more and no less, regardless.  We don't need to apply for as much as 50% from other sources; all that's required is to apply for *something*.  I suspect that the rationale for the requirement is to demonstrate that you're serious about using the sabbatical for research, as opposed to trying to get half your salary for no work.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. When you're not paid, it's normally called a "leave of absence."

Answer (score 3):

In a perfect world, yes.

I work in a 400 year old pontifical university in the Philippines. I was tenured in 2012 which is supposed to entitle me certain leave privileges (LOA without pay, sabbatical leave, study leave etc.) I was not only denied any of these entitlement, but was also fired when I applied.

Comment: Good to know, if this is true I would never consider a professorship in the Phillippines...

Answer (score 3):

In most  universities in **Australia**, you are paid a full salary when you go on sabbatical. You will also typically receive an allowance that hopefully covers most costs associated with travel and accommodation. You may also get an additional allowance if you are travelling with family. That said, such allowances often do not cover the full cost of travel. In such cases it helps  if you have additional sources of academic funds (e.g., grants, consulting funds, etc.).

From what I hear, academics in Australia tend to be eligible to apply for sabbatical more frequently than in other countries (often every three years). That said, obtaining sabbatical is not automatic. You would typically need head of department support presumably based on a strong rationale for the visit in combination with strong research or teaching performance in the preceding years.

Here's a few examples of policies:

- [University of Melbourne Special Studies Program (Long)](http://about.unimelb.edu.au/careers/development/academic/sspl)
- [Deakin University Academic Study Program](https://www.deakin.edu.au/about-deakin/careers-at-deakin/staff-development/academic-study-program)